# Passing decimal through HttpPost

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm loading an object to a view through `HttpGet` and filling `@Html.EditorFor` with the data, I'm displaying the data and I'll make it so the user can edit what he wants and submit the changed object to the controller through HttpPost.

Tere's the code:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.Label("Taxa IVA normal")
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.taxaIVAnormal)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.Label("Taxa IVA intermédio")
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.taxaIVAintermedio)
</div>

//more code
```

The fields are all decimals, but they are displayed with `","` instead of `"."`, so i can't post it back in the controller.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult alteraTaxas()
{
    return View(TaxasRepository.getTaxas().SingleOrDefault());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult alteraTaxas(Taxas tx)
{         
    TaxasRepository.AlteraTaxa(tx);
    return View();
}
```

Is there any way(in the view) to make it so i don't get the validation "its not a number" when i use `","` do separate de decimal cases.
I tried this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => (double)model.taxaIVAnormal)
```

But id doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that this is a Spanish site and model.taxaIVAnormal is string.  The easiest way to get things working maybe to set the globalization parameter in web.config file:

```
<globalization uiCulture="es" culture="es-MX" />
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0(v=vs.71).aspx for more info.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same problem it seems you are having. May want to try this out and see if it works for you as it worked for the other user.

[Parse decimal in view model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994308/mvc-3-parse-decimal-in-view-model)